# GitHub link on Stack Overflow account

Tags: discussion, profile-page, accounts

I inserted a link to my [GitHub account](https://github.com/omerbp) (via 'edit your profile' page) to my Stack Overflow account. However, it does not seem to appear in my profile.

Where is the GitHub account located in the user profile page?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I see it right there [on your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3523490/omerbp?tab=profile), next to the GitHub icon (the Octocat silhouette):

> [image: Profile details with Github icon and username circled]

Comment: Cool, silly me. This post was worth it only because of learning its called **the Octocat silhouette**